# Coldfusion 2018 - Best way to display progress animation during long insert query?

Tags: coldfusion, progress-bar, coldfusion-2018

I have a page that can potentially do a long insert query that takes upwards of 30 seconds to 1 minute. I would like to display an animation on the page while this is happening to let people know it's processing. What is the best way to do this with CF 2018?

Comment: What's best depends on your situation.  What does the user see once the page has finished processing?

Comment: They are redirected to a table that shows the results. They are uploading a csv file with sometimes thousands of entries and I am processing that and creating entries in a DB table. Once they select the file and hit submit I wanted to display an animation while it is processing. Once finished redirect them to the index page.

Comment: In old CFML server we used cfprogressbar tag to achieve this. But now a days most of the UI tags are deprecated in Coldfusion. As you tagged your requirement is belongs to cf2018 so most of the UI tag not supported.
So I suggest to by below links.  It's will met your requirements. https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/cfprogressbar/index.html

Comment: Either `<cfflush>` or `<cfthread>`  might be appropriate for your situation.  Something else that might be an option is to email the results instead of making the user wait.  This would involve `<cfthread>`.

Comment: I found the best solution that works for me is by using a combination of css and Javascript to handle this.  I haven't used this specific solution [here](https://idiallo.com/blog/loading-bar-for-page-load) but I've done something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am going to play around with this shortly and see what I can come up with.